# Change target of a delegate subscribed to an event

Tags: c#

I have an idea to change the target of a delegate instead of subscribing/unsubscribing to the event.

I've an instance (simple singleton) of control with a `TextBox`:

```
public partial class MyControl : UserControl
{
    private delegate void myKeyUpEvent(object sender, KeyEventArgs args);
    private myKeyUpEvent delKeyUp = (s, k) => { }; // empty starting delegate

    private static MyControl Instance = new MyControl(); 

    private MyControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        myTextBox.KeyUp += new KeyEventHandler(delKeyUp); // add my delegate
    }

    public static void ChangeAction(Action<KeyEventArgs> keyAction = null)
    {
        if (keyAction != null) Instance.delKeyUp = (s, k) => { keyAction(k); };
    }
}
```

Then I would like to use it in my main thread like this:

```
MyControl.ChangeAction((k) => { Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => { MessageBox.Show("Works!"); }); });
```

It turns out that it is not working as I would wish. I don't get any Messages when the event is fired.

Is it possible to change the target of a delegate subscribed to an event?

Comment: Where do you place your UserControl?

Comment: Assigning (=) event handlers, rather than attaching (+=) and detaching (-=), can cause bugs in your code. You should never do direct assignment of event handlers.

Comment: @Enigmativity You are right. It is just loose thinking and seeking a gap where the hedge is whole.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing the value of `delKeyUp` won't change the handlers of the `KeyUp` event.

You have to first remove your current handler, and then add a new one.

```
private static KeyEventHandler _keyEventHandler;

public static void ChangeAction(Action<KeyEventArgs> keyAction)
{
    if (keyAction == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("keyAction");

    //create KeyUp handler
    MyKeyUpEvent newKeyUpEvent = (s, k) => { keyAction(k) };
    KeyEventHandler newKeyEventHandler = new KeyEventHandler(newKeyUpEvent);

    //Assign handler
    myTextBox.KeyUp -= _keyEventHandler;
    myTextBox.KeyUp += newKeyEventHandler;

    //keep reference to new handler
    _keyEventHandler = newKeyEventHandler;
}
```

Since you'll have to keep track of the current `KeyUp` handler, you'll also have to change the constructor.

```
private MyControl()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    _keyEventHandler = new KeyEventHandler(delKeyUp); // add my delegate
    myTextBox.KeyUp += _keyEventHandler;
}
```

Also:

- It doesn't make much sense to make the `keyAction` parameter optional, if you're not gonna do anything if the parameter isn't there.
- Note that this isn't thread-safe.

Comment: I hoped that it would work like that: I set a pointer in event to delegate, the delegate points to method, and I can change that second pointer. But it seems not to work like that. It was just an idea and thought. Yeah, I'm aware that your code is not thread-safe, but in my simple case it is ok - it runs on one thread. Nevertheless your code helped me to make mine a little clearer. Thank you.

Comment: @Romasz The `KeyEventHandler` still points to the delegate you created. The thing is, when you call `ChangeAction`, you create a whole new delegate. The `KeyEventHandler` isn't aware of that. It's the same thing as this: `list.Add(str); str = "new string";`. The list will point to your *old* string.

Comment: By the way, I don't think you need to declare your own delegate `MyKeyUpEvent` (unless you have other uses for it). You could simply "convert" the given `keyAction` to a `KeyEventHandler` directly, i.e. `KeyEventHandler handler = (s, k) => keyAction(k);`

Comment: You are right with this string, but I thought it's like with reference type - if I have `List<class>` and a `string name` in this class object and then `list.Add(class object); class object.name = "new name";` then `new name` will be in class object and also in list. That is what I tried to do with those delegates. I agree with this short version my code already looks like: `newKeyEventHandler = new KeyEventHandler((s, k) => { keyAction(k); });`

Comment: @Romasz The difference is, in your example, `class` is a reference that always points to the same object. The `list` points to the same object as `class`. So, if you change the object's members, both `class` and `list` would reflect those changes. But if you created a whole new object (`class = new object()`), then `list` and `class` would be pointing to *different* objects.

Comment: Right. So it means in simple words that `(s,k) =>` means `new delegate`. Is it right?

Comment: @Romasz Exactly. This code is creating a new anonymous method and assigning it to the delegate variable: `del = () => {}`. Much like `str = "hello"` is creating a brand new string and assigning it to the variable `str`.

Comment: Great - now it is clear to me what is happening in the code. Thank you for your time. Have a nice evening.